# OME series: not an ome-tiff master file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, warnings, tiff, imread, fiji

I am trying to open 2 dimensional tiff files with extension ".tif", whose exact name is "IMG0014_PKMO1_4000_T0002_STAR_580.tif", with the code

```
from tifffile import imread
image = imread(path_low)
```

It manages to do every operation after those lines, as if it finally suceeded in opening every ome tif file. It manages to blur it and saves its correctly to another path. I don't understand why the following errors occur and where it comes from, and how to delete it:

> OME series: not an ome-tiff master file
> OME series: failed to read 'IMG0014_PKMO1_4000_T0002_STAR_580.STED.ome.tif'

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's a warning in the log. The file is part of a multi-file OME-TIFF dataset but the main file containing the OME metadata could not be found. You should be able to disable the warning by passing `is_ome=False` to imread.